# Should I create a Enum or a Class, if the type in Enum only use once

Tags: java, performance, class, enums, enumeration

In Java, Wondering which solution is the best coding practice and performance?

So if I created following enum, but for each type of Enum, it will only use for **once**.

```
public enum DifferType{
    TypeA("TypeA", True, "Monthly", False),
    TypeB("TypeB", False, "Daily",True),
    TypeC("TypeC", True, "Yearly",False),
    TypeD("TypeD", False, "Monthly",True)
    TypeE("TypeE", True, "Yearly",False),
    TypeF("TypeF", False, "Monthly",True),
    TypeG("TypeG", True, "Yearly",False),
    TypeH("TypeH", False, "Monthly",True)
    }
```

Or a subclass, can create a new object and set the field whenever its using?

```
   public class DifferType{

    public DifferType(String name, Boolean isDown, String frequency, String isLeft){
    this.name = name;
    this.isDown = down;
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.isLeft = isLeft;
    }

}
DifferType TypeA = new DifferType("TypeA", True, "Monthly", False);
 DifferType TypeB = new DifferType("TypeB", False, "Daily",True)
.....etc
```

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but avoid boxed types like `Boolean` until you need to store instances in a collection, etc. A primitive like `boolean` guarantees  null-safe behavior; don't throw that away for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

They serve different purposes.  An `enum` is (typically) for when you can *enumerate* (hence the name) all the possible or meaningful values for some `Object`.  So if `TypeA` ... `TypeH` cover *all* possible values, an `enum` is the best.  If you're just providing some examples or commonly used examples, then the class is *probably* the best option*.

Number of uses shouldn't really be a consideration here (at least in my opinion).  APIs evolve and change overtime, and you may well find that thing you previously only used once is now used all over the place.

---

* There are times when having an `enum` and `interface` combination works for cases like this too.  Such as:

```
interface ThingDoer {
    void doThing();
}

enum CommonThingDoers implements ThingDoer {
    _1() {
        @Override
        public void doThing() {}
    },
    _2() {
        @Override
        public void doThing() {}    
    } // etc...
}
```

Which allows for extension, but also says 'these are all the values I'm currently *expecting* to see.